# Remove/ reduce bottom margin from well/ paenl

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use  a well.
I find that the bottom margin is too much (20px).
What is the recommended way of reducing the margin?
The same question is true for panel, which creates the same bottom margin.
Is there a built in class with smaller margin? should I use my own?

```
 <div class="well well-sm">
     Where did you spot the dish?
 </div>
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search places">
```

Answer (score 3):

The bottom margin is defined at `bootstrap.css`

```
.well {
min-height: 20px;
padding: 19px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

If you want to decrease this margin for all `well` in your website, the easiest way is to change it in that file

```
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

If you want to decrease the margin only for this `well` you can define the `margin-bottom` at the tag of the desired `well`

```
 <div class="well well-sm" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
     Where did you spot the dish?
 </div>
```